# Include php page with variable

Tags: php, include

I know that it is possible to include php file with variables. It looks like this sample.

```
include 'http://www.example.com/file.php?foo=1&bar=2';
```

How to include php file on local file system (instead of url) with variables? Smth like that.

```
include 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2';
```

Is it possible?

**UPDATE**
I wanna get variable from index page and include the file with exact variable from local system to content div.
smth like that

```
<?php
$foo=$_GET['foo'];
$bar=$_GET['bar'];

?>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="content">
<?php
include 'file.php?foo='.$foo.'&bar='.$bar;
?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: for local files it's impossible. Set your variables before including the other files. As you can get GET variables by `$_GET` so you can set them also with `$_GET`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables are simply available in the file to be included. There is no file scope for variables.

so if you do this

```
$foo=1; $bar=2;
include 'file.php';
```

`$foo` and `$bar` will be available in the `file.php`.

The variables declared above this included statement will be available in the `file.php` file.

Comment: this wouldn't work. he wants to pass the variables explicit. so you have to assume, that in `file.php` he's setting the variables via `$_GET`

Answer (score 1):

Included files have access to whatever variables are defined in the scope they were called in. So, anything you define before the `include` will be set in the included file.

```
# foo.php

$foo = 'bar';
include 'bar.php';

# bar.php

echo $foo;
```

When `foo.php` is run, the output will be 'bar'.

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect the variables to do? Maybe something like this:

```
<?
$_GET["foo"] = "1";
$_GET["bar"] = "2";
include "file.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have it reversed: should be $foo = $_GET['foo'] etc.